# Отслеживание действий на сайте через APP

Tags: java, android

Всем привет! К примеру в моем приложении есть ссылка которая ведет на сайт. И я говорю пользователю "зайди на сайт, выполни действия и ты получишь бонус в приложении"... Но как отследить выполнил ли он действия или нет? Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Каждый экземпляр приложения должен добавлять к ссылке уникальный реферальный код, а бэкенд должен начинать для запросов с реферальным кодом сессию, отслеживать действия в сессии и записывать в БД факт выполнения целевого.